# Removing Punctuation python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Before you post the link to best way to remove punctuation.

I am creating a madLib game that replaces words in a paragraph with nouns,adverbs,verbs,adjectives etc; it is supposed to take a random word from a seperate file and print it to the paragraph where appropriate ie a verb running would be put into the postion where the paragraph states VERB. The only problem I'm having is that I am unable to do this when there is punctuation beside the word I am to replace. Such as VERB, or VERB!

My question is how do I replace all those values while keeping the punctuation there.

Comment: Do you have to format blanks as UPPERCASE_PART_OF_SPEECH? If you can, try to change it to "{part-of-speech}". (I.e. `This is a {verb}!`). Python has a very versatile string formatter that would be perfect for dealing with things like this.

Answer (score 2):

```
noun1="Donkey"
print("This should print a %s here"%(noun1))
```

Essentially, you can get your input variables, and treat them like this example.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of your use case, but does `replace` with the `count` parameter set to 1 work?

```
>>> test = 'This is a VERB! Whoa, a VERB? Yeah, a VERB!#$%'
>>> test.replace('VERB', 'running', 1)
'This is a running! Whoa, a VERB? Yeah, a VERB!#$%'
>>> test.replace('VERB', 'running', 1).replace('VERB', 'swimming', 1).replace('VERB', 'sleeping', 1)
'This is a running! Whoa, a swimming? Yeah, a sleeping!#$%'
```

Naturally you'd have to do some adjustments for the number of repetitions, but it should handle the punctuation fine.

As per @mgilson's suggestion below, you could remove the numerous calls to `replace` by doing something like:

```
In [14]: s = 'This is a VERB! Whoa, a VERB? Yeah, a VERB!#$%'

In [15]: verbs = ['running', 'jumping', 'swimming']

In [16]: reduce(lambda x, y: x.replace('VERB', y, 1), verbs, s)
Out[16]: 'This is a running! Whoa, a jumping? Yeah, a swimming!#$%'
```

This uses the `reduce` function to run `replace` on the main string, using the values in `verbs` as the ones to replace. The final argument to reduce is the string itself, which will contain the result of the replacement on each iteration (and will be the 'normal' string at the outset).

Comment: Argv!  I was just typing this (+1).  You could probably even get rid of the `test.replace().replace().replace()...` using a `reduce` :)

Comment: @mgilson Haha, I was channeling my inner mgilson.

Comment: @mgilson I can safely say that you saying that made me try to understand reduce better. Updating with what I think works, and as always, thanks for pushing my thinking :)

Comment: @mgilson I think I owe you royalties - used this `reduce` construct for the third time today. Thanks again for getting me thinking outside the box :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the sub function from the re module.  Capture the character after the word, then substitute the word with the new word and append the captured punctuation using a backreference:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "VERB,"
>>> print re.sub(r'VERB([\,\!\?\;\.]?)', r'newword\1', s)
newword,
```

You can expand the character class `[\,\!\?\;\.]` to include whatever punctuation you expect to encounter, this is just an example.

Answer (score 0):

The sub function works fine for your problem

```
from re import *
contents = 'The !ADJECTIVE! panda walked to the !NOUN? and then *VERB!. A nearby <NOUN> was unaffected by these events.'
print('Enter an adjective: ', end = '')
adj = input()
print('Enter a noun: ', end = '')
noun1 = input()
print('Enter a verb: ', end = '')
verb = input()
print('Enter a noun: ', end = '')
noun2 = input()
contents = sub(r'adjective',adj,contents,count = 1, flags = IGNORECASE)
contents = sub(r'noun',noun1,contents,count = 1, flags = IGNORECASE)
contents = sub(r'verb',verb,contents,count = 1, flags = IGNORECASE)
contents = sub(r'noun',noun2,contents,count = 1, flags = IGNORECASE)
```

The sub function takes five arguments. re.sub(expression to find, string to replace, string in which replacement is done, count i.e, the number of occurrences should be replaced, IGNORECASE find all cases irrespective of upper or lower case)
Output of the code

```
Enter an adjective: silly
Enter a noun: chandelier
Enter a verb: screamed
Enter a noun: pickup truck
The !silly! panda walked to the !NOUN? and then *VERB!. A nearby <NOUN> was
unaffected by these events.
The !silly! panda walked to the !chandelier? and then *VERB!. A nearby <NOUN> was
unaffected by these events.
The !silly! panda walked to the !chandelier? and then *screamed!. A nearby <NOUN> was
unaffected by these events.
The !silly! panda walked to the !chandelier? and then *screamed!. A nearby <pickup truck> was
unaffected by these events.
```

The punctuation marks are unaffected by these events.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

[string.punctuation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.punctuation) contains following characters:

> '!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~'

You can use translate and maketrans functions to map punctuations to empty values (replace)

```
import string

'This, is. A test! VERB! and VERB,'.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
```

Output:

> 'This is A test VERB and VERB'